# A direction vector can be determined through the difference of two vectors position.

Tags: vectors

I am learning about vectorial equation, and i have a doubt about this statement:

> A direction vector can be determined through the difference of two
>   vectors position.

The direction vector that is determined is the original direction vector or the translated direction vector?

With 'traslated direction vector', i mean to: (**in the two images the red segment is the direction vector)**

[image]

And with 'original direction vector' i mean to:

[image]

And, what is the proof of this statement?

Any advice to better understand this topic is welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're determining the original directional vector. For vector algebra only the direction and magnitude matter, not the position. This is because the components of a vector don't change if you translate it.

It helps to first look at this in one dimension.
On a real number line consider two points. Say $a=3$ and $b=5$.
We may think of these as vectors. 
[image]

The quantity $b-a$ represents the distance between $a$ and $b$.
Also the vector $b-a$ points from $a$ `towards` $b$. If $b-a$ is positive then the vector points towards positive side, else it points towards negative side.

[image]

Similarly the vector $a-b$ points from $b$ `towards` $a$. 
[image]

Next you can extrapolate this to $2D$.
For the vectors $a$ and $b$, the vector $b-a$ points from $a$ towards $b$ :
[image]

[image]

Adding vectors $a$ and $b-a$ gives the vector $b$.
So to get any vector between $a$ and $b$ we may scale $b-a$ and then add it to $a$ : 
 $$a + t(b-a)$$
$0\le t\le 1$.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97268/discussion-on-answer-by-rsadhvika-a-direction-vector-can-be-determined-through-t).

Answer (score 1):

A line is parametrized by knowing *some* point on it (given by the vector $\vec x_0$ from the origin) and its direction vector $\vec v$. Then the vector from the origin to an arbitrary point on the line can be written as
$$\vec x = \vec x_0 + t\vec v \quad\text{for some value of the scalar } t.$$

Note that if you know two points on the line, this corresponds to such expressions for two different values of $t$, and so you recover the direction vector (or a nonzero scalar multiple of it) by subtracting the two vectors:  If $\vec x_1 = \vec x_0 + t\vec v$ and $\vec x_2 = \vec x_0 + s\vec v$ (where $s$ and $t$ are different scalars), then
$$\vec x_2 - \vec x_1 = (\vec x_0 + s\vec v) - (\vec x_0 + t\vec v) = (s-t)\vec v,$$
as desired.

Comment: Good, i think that i have a problem in the concept of position vector. The position vector is only a point of the line? If this is true,  so i can say that the statement can be: "A direction vector can be determined through the difference of two different vectors in the line"? Since say: "difference of two different position vector" is the same that "difference of two different vectors in the line", im right?

Comment: And still with the doubt, according to the statement " A direction vector can be determined through the difference of two position vector", the phrase "A direction vector"  what means? The original direction vector($\vec{v})$, the traslated direction vector(origin different from $(0, 0) ) $or the traslated scalated direction vector(origin different from $(0, 0)$ and multiplied by some $t$ number)?

Comment: A line *through the origin* is given by $\vec x = t\vec v$ as $t$ varies over all real numbers (scalars). In this case $\vec v$ (or any nonzero scalar multiple of it) is called the direction vector of the line. When we take a line parallel to this, it has the same direction vector, but we've translated it by adding a fixed vector $\vec x_0$.